# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

My Environment:

React Native: 0.50.4

Android Studio: 3.1.1

Gradle: 4.6

Device: Android Emulator (Any Android OS)

I'm updating my current react native app to start using Firebase. I'm using the `react-native-firebase` package to integrate them, BUT I'm pretty positive that that isn't the problem since my issues appear before I start dealing with that stuff.

Here is some of my source:

`build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

'app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ourdailystrength.mobile.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
    //    transitive = false
    //}
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.50.4"  // From node_modules

    // firebase modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1"

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Once I build and run the app, I get the following error:

```
           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
                  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:2)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6378)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5939)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5856)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1623)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ourdailystrength.mobile.android-mFoP1bOjnUTgeG_cDvnVkg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ourdailystrength.mobile.android-mFoP1bOjnUTgeG_cDvnVkg==/lib/x86, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.ourdailystrength.mobile.android-mFoP1bOjnUTgeG_cDvnVkg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:2) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6378) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5939) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5856) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:193) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1623) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

I did try and upgrade from `12.0.1` to `15.0.0` and have it build and run fine, but when it came to sending Firebase a message, it complained about the Google Play services being out of date. Got this error:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 12446024
W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
```

I ran this on Android P, so I wouldn't think the Google Play services would be out of date on that. I couldn't find where Google documents the releases for google play services, since I have a hunch 12.4.51.000 doesn't exist yet.

I've tried to find answers to this and none have helped yet. Anything will help. Thanks!

Comment: The version of Play services is not tied to the version of Android.  Play updates itself on emulator images that have the play store on it - these images are what you should be using to work with Firebase.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've tried with Nexus 5X which has Play store installed, but it still gives the NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution.

1. Update everything to `15.0.0` in the dependencies. Yes, it will keep giving you the error for out of date google play services, but that's ok.
2. Create a new emulator with Google Play store installed (for now, I think it's just Nexus 5 and 5X).
3. Open the emulator and update google play services. You'll need to first open Google Play and sign in. Once that's done, you should get a notification to update google play services.
4. Once it's finished updating, you can check in the settings as you what version it is and if it's new enough (which it should).
5. Uninstall the app and reinstall the app. It should be working now.